# Intent not sending EXTRA_TEXT when Intent.ACTION_SEND is used

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-intent-chooser

I am trying to send a link from a fragment to the same application via Intent.ACTION_SEND.
When the share intent is sent, the list of applications have my application which on click takes me to an activity within my app, where i am trying to receive data via intent but the bundle is empty.

**SENDING DATA AS PATH**

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        final ArrayList<Intent> shareIntents;
        try {
            shareIntents = getExternalShareIntents(context, shareIntent);

            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, shareIntents.toArray(new 
            Parcelable[]{}));
            chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(chooserIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT), path);
            context.startActivity(chooserIntent);
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**RECEIVING INTENT IN ACTIVITY**

```
 bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        Intent intent0 = getIntent();
        String action = intent0.getAction();
        String type = intent0.getType();

        if (intent0 != null) {
            //if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) D
                imageUri = intent0.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                Toast.makeText(NewHomeScreenActivty.this, "onResume " + imageUri, 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // }
        }
```

**RECEIVING ACTIVITY IN MANIFEST**

```
  <activity
            android:name=".app.activity.NewHomeScreenActivty"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label=""
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I am unable to receive any data passed via intent.

Comment: `EXTRA_TEXT` goes on the `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`. You seem to be putting it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this in the sending data class:

```
chooserIntent.putExtra(chooserIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT), path);
```

Use the following:

```
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, path);
```